# R: Losing data during subsetting (data.table)

Tags: r, data.table

I am losing data when I try to subset my data.table.

Here's the .csv which the file is written from

```
Timestamp,Date,Time,SN,A.Ms.Amp,A.Ms.Vol,A.Ms.Watt,Pac
2013-10-01 12:00:00,2013-10-01,12:00:00,2110000001,23.04,465.43,10723,13544.5
2013-10-01 12:00:00,2013-10-01,12:00:00,2110000002,7.81,474.16,3704,6860
2013-10-01 12:00:00,2013-10-01,12:00:00,2110000003,6.97,484.19,3374,6661
2013-10-01 12:05:00,2013-10-01,12:05:00,2110000001,23.19,467.05,10830,13576
2013-10-01 12:05:00,2013-10-01,12:05:00,2110000002,8.4,462.52,3883.5,7366.5
2013-10-01 12:05:00,2013-10-01,12:05:00,2110000003,7.72,470.6,3631,7169
2013-10-01 12:10:00,2013-10-01,12:10:00,2110000001,23.98,470.29,11278.5,14127.5
2013-10-01 12:10:00,2013-10-01,12:10:00,2110000002,8.62,458.47,3952,7475.5
2013-10-01 12:10:00,2013-10-01,12:10:00,2110000003,7.9,462.62,3654,7182.33
2013-10-01 12:15:00,2013-10-01,12:15:00,2110000001,24.27,467.37,11342,14193
2013-10-01 12:15:00,2013-10-01,12:15:00,2110000002,8.61,458.96,3949,7502
2013-10-01 12:15:00,2013-10-01,12:15:00,2110000003,8.13,458.31,3725,7338
2013-10-01 12:20:00,2013-10-01,12:20:00,2110000001,22.3,461.71,10279.5,12735.5
2013-10-01 12:20:00,2013-10-01,12:20:00,2110000002,8.51,461.87,3929,7553.5
2013-10-01 12:20:00,2013-10-01,12:20:00,2110000003,7.83,462.19,3618.5,7331.5
```

Here's the code I ran:

```
library(data.table)
a<-fread("complete1.csv")
a[,`:=`(Timestamp=ymd_hms(Timestamp),
Date=ymd(Date),
SN=as.factor(SN))]
a[SN==c("2110000001","2110000002"),c("Timestamp","Date","Time","SN","A.Ms.Watt","Pac"),with=FALSE]
```

I get this output:

```
   > a[SN==c("2110000001","2110000002"),c("Timestamp","Date","Time","SN","A.Ms.Watt","Pac"),with=FALSE]
             Timestamp       Date     Time         SN A.Ms.Watt     Pac
1: 2013-10-01 12:00:00 2013-10-01 12:00:00 2110000001   10723.0 13544.5
2: 2013-10-01 12:00:00 2013-10-01 12:00:00 2110000002    3704.0  6860.0
3: 2013-10-01 12:10:00 2013-10-01 12:10:00 2110000001   11278.5 14127.5
4: 2013-10-01 12:10:00 2013-10-01 12:10:00 2110000002    3952.0  7475.5
5: 2013-10-01 12:20:00 2013-10-01 12:20:00 2110000001   10279.5 12735.5
6: 2013-10-01 12:20:00 2013-10-01 12:20:00 2110000002    3929.0  7553.5
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(SN, c("2110000001", "2110000002")) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Unfortunately, I don't quite understand the warnings. But I am losing data at every 12:xx:x5 intervals (e.g. 12:00:05). What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a `data.table` problem, but an improper operator problem. The operator `==` is vectorized. See what happens when you look at:

```
a[,list(Timestamp,SN, SN == c("2110000001","2110000002"))]

              Timestamp         SN    V3
 1: 2013-10-01 12:00:00 2110000001  TRUE
 2: 2013-10-01 12:00:00 2110000002  TRUE
 3: 2013-10-01 12:00:00 2110000003 FALSE
 4: 2013-10-01 12:05:00 2110000001 FALSE
 5: 2013-10-01 12:05:00 2110000002 FALSE
 6: 2013-10-01 12:05:00 2110000003 FALSE
 7: 2013-10-01 12:10:00 2110000001  TRUE
 8: 2013-10-01 12:10:00 2110000002  TRUE
 9: 2013-10-01 12:10:00 2110000003 FALSE
10: 2013-10-01 12:15:00 2110000001 FALSE
11: 2013-10-01 12:15:00 2110000002 FALSE
12: 2013-10-01 12:15:00 2110000003 FALSE
13: 2013-10-01 12:20:00 2110000001  TRUE
14: 2013-10-01 12:20:00 2110000002  TRUE
15: 2013-10-01 12:20:00 2110000003 FALSE
Warning message:
In SN == c("2110000001", "2110000002") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

This is documented in the R language manual, in [Operators](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Operators):

> R deals with entire vectors of data at a time, and most of the elementary operators and basic mathematical functions like `log` are vectorized (as indicated in the table above). This means that e.g. adding two vectors of the same length will create a vector containing the element-wise sums, implicitly looping over the vector index. This applies also to other operators like `-`, `*`, and `/` as well as to higher dimensional structures.

If you want `TRUE` when `SN` is either of the values `c("2110000001","2110000002")`, use `%in%`, like

```
SN %in% c("2110000001","2110000002")
```